# Removing last element in list while iterating causes error

Tags: c++, list, iterator

I have a list of chars and I'm trying to remove consecutive duplicates e.g. `{'a', 'b', 'a', 'a', 'a'}` becomes `{'a', 'b', 'a'}`. When removing the last 'a' `itr2` points to nothing and I get a "list iterator not dereferencable" error. I understand why this happens but I'm having difficulties resolving it. How can this be resolved and are there any nicer ways to do this?

Here's my code:

```
void removeDuplicates(list<char> &myList)
{
    list<char>::iterator itr;
    list<char>::iterator itr2;
    for (itr = myList.begin(); itr != myList.end();)
    {
        itr2 = next(itr, 1);
        if (tolower(*itr) == tolower(*itr2))
        {
            myList.erase(itr2);
        }
        else
        {
            ++itr;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The statement

```
itr2 = next(itr, 1);
```

might give you the `end` iterator, you must check for that before you try to dereference it

Something like

```
if (itr2 != mylist.end() && tolower(*itr) == tolower(*itr2)) { ... }
```

Comment: Thanks, this is perfect.

Answer (score 3):

There is already a function on list that removes consecutive duplicates called [`unique`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list/unique).

```
myList.unique();
```

**Update**:

To ignore casing then you can use the algorithm version of [`unique`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/unique).

```
auto end = std::unique(s.begin(), s.end(), [](char l, char r)
{
    return tolower(l) == tolower(r)
});
```

Comment: Thanks but I need to also ignore casing

Comment: Updated to handle case.

Answer (score 0):

A simpler C++11 solution. You can solve this by using one iterator instead of 2. Simply assign myList.erase back to the iterator itself. This would delete current element and move the iterator forward.

```
void removeDuplicates(list<char> &myList)
{
  list<char>::iterator itr;

  for (itr = myList.begin(); itr != myList.end();)
  {
    if (tolower(*itr) == tolower(*std::prev(itr)))
    {
        itr = myList.erase(itr);
    }
    else
    {
        ++itr;
    }
  }
  for (itr : myList)
    cout << itr <<" ";
}
```

Working ideone example [here](http://ideone.com/BpYSA1)

Comment: Though this is cleaner, technically you are still using another iterator which is returned from `std::prev()`, just like OP using the iterator returned from `next()`